# How to query most favorited questions for a particular tag?

Tags: support, tags, search, data-explorer, bookmarks

In Stack Overflow search, I can type `[ember.js]lastactive:1d` to list questions which have been modified within the last day. In the same way, are there any advanced search options to list questions which have been favorited the most for a particular tag?

Like the pattern below, which is not working:

```
[ember.js]favorites:5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That pattern is not working because it's not supported (also, the tag is [ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember.js); you were missing a dot). You can only search in the favourite questions of certain users (including yourself) with the `infavorites:` option. For these kind of filters, you should resort to [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

[I just built a query for you](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/594894/most-favorited-questions-for-a-certain-tag?minimumFavoriteScore=5&tagName=ember.js); the following questions are the top results:

- [Separate REST JSON API server and client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941249) (290 stars)
- [SPA best practices for authentication and session management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963273) (104 stars)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458436 (92 stars)

For reference, here is the full query:

```sql
SELECT p.Id AS [Post Link], p.FavoriteCount, p.Title, p.Body
  FROM Posts AS p
  INNER JOIN PostTags AS pt ON p.Id = pt.PostId
  INNER JOIN Tags AS t ON t.Id = pt.TagId
  WHERE p.FavoriteCount >= ##minimumFavoriteScore:int##
    AND t.TagName = ##tagName:string##
  ORDER BY p.FavoriteCount DESC
```

Remember that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning, so the actual scores might be a bit off.

Comment: Hey this is super-useful. I never knew how to do anything useful with SEDE till now.